# Отключается виртуальная среда в PyCharm прошу помощи

Tags: python, pycharm, pip, venv, файловые-пути

Помогите решить проблему - сломал всю голову. Заключается проблема в виртуальном окружении для python в PyCharm.
Всё делал по инструкциям несколько раз, удалял все проекты под ноль и создавал новый проект, выбирал ему по умолчанию виртуальное окружение, заходил в настройки и проверял - в разделе: Python Interpreter всё было как надо, только pip и в пути в скобочках указано наименование моего проекта! Однако после того, как создал так три разных проекта, потом решил открыть один из них, чтобы начать работу, то он мне выдал невалидный путь. Захожу в раздел: Python Interpreter и вижу приписку [invalid].
И так происходит всегда, если создаю с нуля. Постоянно после перезахода в проект - он выдаёт что не нашёл виртуальное окружение...
Помогите

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]